# How to use ternary operator with Mule expression evaluators

Tags: mule

In my Mule flow I want to use a ternary operation in a message enrichment element.

For example, here is the existing line that throws an error when the source is null:

```
        <enricher doc:name="Add revision number" target="#[variable:rev]" source="#[json:_rev]">
```

Here is the line when trying to use the ternary operation:

```
        <enricher doc:name="Add revision number" target="#[variable:rev]" source="#[json:_rev == null ? '' : json:_rev]">
```

If a null is returned from the enrichment source, I want to return an empty string instead.  I don't want errors to be thrown when Mule tries to use the 'setProperty()' function to assign a null value.

Currently the ternary example works, but it returns 'false' (not as a string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the Mule Expression Language (MEL) but the old evaluator syntax, which doesn't support ternary expressions.

EDIT:

I suggest your get the [MEL cheatsheet](http://blogs.mulesoft.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/refcard-mel.pdf) and see how JSON handling is done.

From the partial information you provide, I think you'll need a `json-to-object-transformer` in the response phase of your HTTP outbound endpoint (that fetches JSON right?). Then you can use a MEL ternary expression in your enricher.

Comment: =(  So if I want to check for nulls, is there another syntax I can use?  I wanted to also try putting some groovy behind the <http:outbound> element in the message enricher, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Added a suggestion to my answer.